# Connect ssh through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I have ssh access, I can go to the terminal in my Mac and ssh to the production server and connect to file system and also able to connect to mongo from terminal, but I want to connect from nodejs project running in my local machine. My intention is easy to connect to the production server from web UI running in my local without using the terminal.
Can someone please suggest a way how to ssh to the server and executes commands in ssh server from nodejs.

Comment: you can use shellJs https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Comment: i have only .ssh/id_rsa file and server name only, but shelljs doesn't contains any code snippet for it, Can you provide the code snippet that takes ssh file and server name and it needs to connect after that i want to execute commands in it.

Comment: Here is a link on how to do just that: https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-to-ssh-using-nodejs